# Software for logical mapping of concepts?

Tags: windows, mind-mapping

I am a very procedural thinker, and for my goals I like to break each task into smaller sub-tasks repeatedly until I get a many-layer hierarchy with a series of fairly small, simple tasks being at the bottom.

Historically I have done this via Excel, but the problem is for each task or subtask (let's call them nodes) I need to have related information, logical thought processes and deductions relevant to that node. The problem with doing this in excel is that things become cluttered visually and I get overwhelmed with the data.

So what I need is a software (preferably for Windows 10) which allows me to make nodes which have any number of children I desire, and which allows me to have numerous data inputs associated with any node I want, each treated as their own object, and "labelable". The UI should be such that I can select a node to pull up/access any of the related content I want.

Anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s some of my not-quite formalized notes on Mind Mapping software

## MindMapper Software Comparison

### MindNote Lite

[MindNode page on iTunes Preview](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/mindnode/id312220102?mt=8)

- Default graphic representation: branches
- Can only do tree branches
- Can do new multiple Main nodes
- Doesn’t support Collapse/Expand

#### Navigation

Zoom in/out/to fit

#### Exports to

- PDF
- Freemind
- OPML
- Image
- Text

**Notes**

Clean UI
A little basic, therefore good for beginners

---

### SimpleMind Free

[SimpleMind Desktop comparison page](http://www.simpleapps.eu/simplemind/desktop/osx)

Default: Bubble with dotted lines

#### Navigation

Zoom in/out/to fit

- Can’t select multiple bubbles and move them
- Cant change style of interconnecting (join) lines
- Can move join lines from node to node
- Supports drag & drop from Apple Color Picker
- Supports Collapse/Expand

#### Exports to

PDF (via Mac OSX Print-to-PDF)

**Notes**

A bit like Omnigraffle

---

### [MindMeister](http://www.mindmeister.com)

Web
iOS

---

### NovaMind

Pricey
Subscription model

---

### Xmind

---

### FreeMind

---

### CmapTools

---

### [Mindmup](http://www.mindmup.com)

With regard to task manager integration perhaps check out **[DropTask](http://www.droptask.com)** also.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are looking at project management software, such as MS Project, or the free [Task Juggler](http://www.taskjuggler.org/) or [Open Project](https://www.openproject.org/), etc

For larger projects, I will use Task Juggler, otherwise I am more than happy with ToDolist from Abstract Spoon (gotta love that name ;-).

It is free, runs on Widows and its tree-like project structure certainly will let you `break each task into smaller sub-tasks repeatedly until I get a many-layer hierarchy with a series of fairly small, simple tasks being at the bottom`.

Unlike mind mapping software, it will let you assign people and schedules to sub-projects.

Have a look at the [feature list](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5371/ToDoList-An-effective-and-flexible-way-to-keep-on), take it for a 5 minute test derive and you will soon know if you want project management software or mind mapping.

Obligatory screenshot follows:

[image]